# Rails: Hierarchical select for a model with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hierarchy, ancestry

I need to display a hierarchical structured select menu of categories.

Im using [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) on my categories model so I can create the categories and sub-categories.

In my schema I have another model "oferts" it has a many-to-many relationship with categories so while creating the oferts I want to select the category of the ofert. would be great to if after select the parent then load the childs in another select.

Anyone know how to do this? I took a try but couldn't figure out a simple way. Here is the visual example:

```
 Category 1
    Sub-Cat 1.1
    Sub-Cat 1.2
  Category 2
    Sub-Cat 2.1
    Sub-Cat 2.2
  Category 3
  Category 4
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I just want to confirm your question. You'd like to know how to create an association between category and oferts wherein when you do a `Oferts.first.categories` it will show all the categories related to oferts? Is that it?

Comment: No no srry you missunderstood me, I want to show a select drowdown while creating the ofert that let me select its category in the way I explained avobe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this nice [article](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/comment-page-1/#comment-25) talking about this functionality we could implement it in many of our forms, very nice, the solution was to use a little bit of ajax

Hope this helps you!